# Using a parameter to get others

Tags: c++, parameters, constructor

I have a struct/class that has many attributes among which one is principal. when constructing an instance of this class, the principal attribute must be given in parameter, but any of the others may or may not be provided. When an attribute is not provided as a parameter it should be computed from the principal attribute.

I have no clue on how to write such a class without writing an exponential number of constructors; or using setters after each constructor that would have only one parameter corresponding to the principal attribute.

I give here a minimal example of what would be ideal for me. But this of course doesn't compile:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct StringInfo
{
  string str;
  int importance;

  StringInfo(string strP, int importanceP = strP.length()): 
  str(strP), importance(importanceP){}

};    

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  string test = "test";
  StringInfo info(test);  
  cout << info.importance << endl;
}
```

Do you have any better (non-exponential) solution?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Depends if you can exclude some (or at least one) specific value for each parameter and if the fact a parameter is given or not depends on the other parameters given or not. Then you can write one constructor with setting the parameters as default to one of the excluded values and within the constructor you can check whether a parameter has this default value or not and modify it accordingly.
EDIT: it does not even depend on the order in which you may pass the parameters since you can just pass the default value if the parameter should be computed from the principal one.

Comment: Use the [Boost Parameter Library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/parameter/doc/html/index.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You practically want a behaviour similar to Python's optional parameters, eg :

```
callFunction(param1=2, param3="hello")
```

You can do this in C++ if you have as a member a map of type erased key-value pairs :

```
map<string, ErasedType> _m;
```

The key of the map is a string with the description of the member (it's up to you to choose this).

Let's leave for now `ErasedType`. Provided that you have such a member you could write :

```
class MyClass
{
    map<string, ErasedType> _m;
public:
    MyClass(map<string, ErasedType> const& args) : _m(args) {}
};
```

So that you would only specify the keys you want to and assign specific values for them. An example of constructing the input for such a constructor is

```
map<string, ErasedType> args = { {"arg1", 1}, {"arg1", 1.2} };
```

Then accessing the particular value would take a member function like so :

```
    ErasedType get(string const& name) { return _m[name]; }
```

Now on the `ErasedType` . The most typical approach would be to have it as a union of all possible types you keep :

```
union ErasedType { // this would be a variant type
    int n;
    double d;
    char c;
};
```

A second idea would be to have the map values be each one an instance of the `boost::any` container. A third idea (more old school) would be to use `void*`

### Toy Implementation

```
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/any.hpp>

using namespace std;
using boost::any_cast;

class OptionalMembers
{
    map<string, boost::any> _m;
public:
    OptionalMembers(map<string, boost::any> const& args) : _m(args) 
    {
        // Here you would initialize only those members 
        // not specified in args with your default values
        if (args.end() == args.find("argName")) {  
            // initialize it yourself
        }
        // same for the other members
    }
    template<typename T>
    T get(string const& memberName) {
        return any_cast<T>(_m[memberName]);
    }
};

int main() 
{
    // say I want my OptionalMembers class to contain
    // int    argInt
    // string argString
    // and then more members that won't be given 
    // as arguments to the constuctor

    std::string text("Hello!");
    OptionalMembers object({ { "argInt", 1 }, { "argString", text } });

    cout << object.get<int>("argInt") << endl;
    cout << object.get<string>("argString") << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

In the previous example you are free to have as many "members" as you want and specify each one at will in the constructor

Comment: Thanks for your interesting solution. However I wish i could avoid double initialization of the parameters (using this solution, those who are provided by the user will be first set to default then to the right value).

Comment: @IssamT. Those provided by the user will be initialized in the initializer list (no prior default). Those not provided will be "created" inside the body of the constructor. The implementation steers away from the formal of a "member". Members only exist as tags in a map's keys and a mechanism is devised to store arbitrary types as values.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the [Named-Parameter Idiom](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/ctors#named-parameter-idiom).

Practically, you'd end up with code like

```
Example object = MakeExample().Parameter1().Parameter2(12345).Parameter3(false);
```

Comment: Thanks for your interesting solution. However I wish i could avoid double initialization of the parameters (using this solution, those who are provided by the user will be first set to default then to the right value).